# How to make python 'remember' my pendrive's name?

Tags: python, usb, usb-drive

I'm writing a Python script to copy files from my computer to my USB pendrive. The script iterates trough some  folders and copies the files he finds in them to a folder in my pendrive. It also checks if this folder exists, and if it don't it creates it.
Script works fine in my computer, in which my USB pendrive has letter "Y:\". But if I change computer, the scripts stops working and I need to edit it to match the letter my usb pendrive has taken in new pc. 
What is the way to do this inside my script?
Is there a way, maybe, to give my pendrive the same letter everytime?

Comment: not reliably, no. It's better to perhaps let your script accept the drive letter as input, and show a confirmation dialogue. That's usually how applications do it.

Comment: write your script so that it takes the drive path as a commandline argument (eventually using "Y" as default).

Answer (score 0):

My boss usually hates me for giving this kind of solutions. Once I had to give a file path in a code and I was unable to give that link, so I wrote a code which searches for  file in system and returns path of it.
That's the solution I suggest now, just search for the connected devices and inject into connect devices, if that device is writable your data will go into it.
If you want to be careful, then just use a regular expression to match with usb stick device type.

```
import re
import subprocess
device_re = re.compile("Bus\s+(?P<bus>\d+)\s+Device\s+(?P<device>\d+).+ID\s(?P<id>\w+:\w+)\s(?P<tag>.+)$", re.I)
df = subprocess.check_output("lsusb")
devices = []
for i in df.split('\n'):
    if i:
        info = device_re.match(i)
        if info:
            dinfo = info.groupdict()
            dinfo['device'] = '/dev/bus/usb/%s/%s' % (dinfo.pop('bus'), dinfo.pop('device'))
            devices.append(dinfo)
print devices
```

All the best ! I liked your idea. Ping me if you need some more help.